# underfined reference to CLSID_FileOpenDialog - Mingw64

Tags: c++, c, mingw-w64

I have a whole project that I had to move from one machine to another and since moving the code, it has been coming up with an error of undefined reference to 'CLSID_FileOpenDialog'.

I'm using the x64 8.1.0 Posix SEH release though I have tried a couple of other versions, such as 7.3.0. I need to use the posix version as I have mutexes in my code and these do no work in the win32 versions.

Is there some library of similar that I need to add to the linker to stop this from happening?
I was using Mingw64 on the old machine so cannot understand why this is happening.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2):

Literally after posting this, I noticed that my project settings didn't include the "ole32", "comctl32", "oleaut32" and "uuid" libraries.

Adding these fixes the issue.